# Dynamic algorithm for text auto-correct

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, levenshtein-distance, autocorrect

I am writing an auto-correct program that uses the [levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to correct 
a phrase of no more than 64 charcters based of a specific dictionary containing 8000 words.

The dictionary contains on each line the pair " Word word_frequency".
I use DictionarEntry objects to store those pairs. Class Dictionar Entry has  two fields :
value : stores the word string
freq  : stores the frequency
The dictionary is stored as a LinkedList.
I read from stdin the 64 character string.
before processing it I remove all the spaces. 
"Coo lweather" -> "Coolweather"
I noticed that insead of calculating the levenshtein distance for every prefix , in the last row of the matrix calculated by the levenshtein dynamic( see wikipedia example )
it returns the distances for all the prefixes.

Function lev returns a vector containing the l.distance from second parameter string to all of the first's prefixes, including itself.

My issue is that I have to respect a few additional rules : 
min lev. distance -> min number of words -> maximum frequency sum -> minimum lexicographic 
 That would be explained as  if the total number of solutions is greater than 1 
we take the ones with minimum number of words. If there are still more than one we follow the list of rules.

The dynamic I am applying is something similar to a knapsack dynamic.
 I don't know how to implement the minimum number of words rule ( the maximum frequency one is very similar)

Here is what I have tried so far 
input/output examples where this fails:
"sore reserved" the answer should be so reserved , what I obtain is actually so re served
 I have chosen this method because it is more efficient. The time limit is 2 seconds for Java.

update : 7th of April . I have found the solution to my problem, however the cpu time is too large so I need to optimize it. 
It should be no higher than 2000 ms and it currently is at around 6000 ms. So now my main focus becomes optimizing it.

```
 public static String guess (String input, LinkedList<DictionarEntry> Dictionar){
       String curent = new String();
      String output = new String();

      int costMatrix[][][] = new int [input.length()][8000][input.length()];         
     int index[] = new int[128];
     int prev[]= new int[128];
        int d[]=new int  [128];
        int freq[]= new int[128];
        int wcount[]=new int[128];
        String values[] = new String[128];   
        for (int i=0 ; i < 128 ; i++){
                d[i]=127;
                freq[i]=0;
                wcount[i]=1;
                values[i]="";
        }           
     d[0]=0;
     freq[0]=0;

         for (int i = 0 ; i <input.length(); ++i){  

             curent=input.subSequence(i, input.length()).toString();
             long start =System.currentTimeMillis();
              for (int j = 0 ; j < Dictionar.size();++j){

                  costMatrix[i][j]=lev(Dictionar.get(j).value,curent);
                  for(int k=1;k<costMatrix[i][j].length;++k){

                      if(d[i]+costMatrix[i][j][k]<d[i+k]){
                          d[i+k]= d[i]+costMatrix[i][j][k];
                              values[i+k]=values[i]+Dictionar.get(j).value;
                              freq[i+k]=freq[i]+Dictionar.get(j).freq;
                              index[i+k]=j;
                              prev[i+k]=i;
                              wcount[i+k]=wcount[i]+1;
                      }
                       else if ((d[i]+costMatrix[i][j][k])==d[i+k])
                                        if((wcount[i]+1) <wcount[i+k]){
                              values[i+k]=values[i]+Dictionar.get(j).value;
                              freq[i+k]=freq[i]+Dictionar.get(j).freq;
                              index[i+k]=j;
                              prev[i+k]=i;
                              wcount[i+k]=wcount[i]+1;    
                                        }
                                        else if ((wcount[i]+1)==wcount[i+k])
                                         if((freq[i]+Dictionar.get(j).freq)>freq[i+k]){
                                             values[i+k]=values[i]+Dictionar.get(j).value;
                                             freq[i+k]=freq[i]+Dictionar.get(j).freq;
                                             index[i+k]=j;
                                             prev[i+k]=i;
                                             wcount[i+k]=wcount[i]+1;       
                                         }
                                         else if ((freq[i]+Dictionar.get(j).freq)==freq[i+k]){
                                             if((values[i]+Dictionar.get(j).value).compareTo(values[i+k])>0){
                                                 values[i+k]=values[i]+Dictionar.get(j).value;
                                              freq[i+k]=freq[i]+Dictionar.get(j).freq;
                                              index[i+k]=j;
                                              prev[i+k]=i;
                                              wcount[i+k]=wcount[i]+1;  
                                             }
                                         }
                  }     
              }
              long finished =System.currentTimeMillis();
                    System.out.println((finished-start)); 

      output="";

         } 

          int itr=input.length();
                   while(itr!=0){
      output = Dictionar.get(index[itr]).value + " " + output;
      itr=prev[itr]; 
  } 
     return output;
  }
```

Where should I implement the rules and how ( ideally in a more efficient way than using a matrix)?

In case there are any questions or I have left something unclear please feel free to ask

Comment: *"what I obtain is actually so re served"* [sic]  Just to be clear: your dictionary of 8000 words has "so", "re", "served" and "reserved" but it doesn't have "sore"?

Comment: so reserved would be the correct answer because the levenshtein distance between sore reserved and so reserved is equal ( if you ignore spaces, which I do)but reserved has higher frequency.

Comment: Does it have to be a dynamic algo? Can you use standard java maps, sets, etc?

Comment: Yes, it has to be a dynamic algo. Yes, I can use sets, maps. The immediate optimization that comes into my mind was to create the costMatrix when I read the dictionary items.  In the curent code I read a dictonary item, then calculate levenshtein for it and all of my input's prefixes. Will get back soon with a numeric value for cpu time.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you can't use an existing library like [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) ? It supports [fuzzy queries](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_2_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyQuery.html) that use Levenshtein distance.

Other than that you might want to consider [Suffix Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) to speed up partial string search

Comment: I can't use Apache Lucene because I'm supposed to provide the solution without making use of routines that do that. For example Java has String.levenshtein. I have added the fix to my problem, but now the cpu time is way too high.